# I made a program related with min priority queues, sometimes I need a stl list as a fundamental structure and other times a stl vector structure

Tags: list, templates, vector, priority-queue

//The real problem is that when I work with list I need to comment the instruction for the vector //and viceversa like this (TBH is the template for the container):

```
string strType;
strType = typeid(container).name();
strType = strType.substr(11, 4);
if (strType=="list") {
    // TBH.sort(compa); because I am working with vectors
} else if (strType == "vect") {
    typedef typename container::iterator Position;
    std::sort(TBH.begin(), TBH.end(), compa2);
}
std::cout << "Sort Done\n";
```

//Has c++ a way to avoid this situation without comment the instructions that gave error:
//Error C2039   'sort': is not a member of 'std::vector<Item,std::allocator>'

Comment: overloading (PS: using `typeid(container).name()` is not something that i would recommend at all)

Answer (score 0):

you can create a `function` to do that and overloads it:

```
template<class T>
void sort(std::vector<T>&& v){
    TBH.sort(compa);
}
template<class T>
void sort(std::list<T>&& l){
    typedef typename container::iterator Position;
    std::sort(TBH.begin(), TBH.end(), l);
}
```